# round combo box border

Tags: c#, wpf

friends 
i find this code to make round combo box but i don't  know how to use

is there any one can help how to use this code

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">    
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
        <Border CornerRadius="5">

        </Border>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

what should i do to apply this code to my combo box in wpf

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wpfsldesigner/2010/06/03/creating-and-consuming-resource-dictionaries-in-wpf-and-silverlight/

Comment: You need to override the combobox template.

Comment: Right click `ComboBox` > Edit Template > Edit Copy, and change the template according to your will.

Answer (score 0):

This template you are showing here is just a basic idea, but not something really working. You need to override the full default template and customize it for your needs. Inside of your UserControl’s resources ass a template (just copy and paste) from this link [default combobox template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752094(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
<UserControl.Resources>
<!-- paste the code here-->
<!--Control colors.-->
<Color x:Key="WindowColor">#FFE8EDF9</Color>
<Color x:Key="ContentAreaColorLight">#FFC5CBF9</Color>
<Color x:Key="ContentAreaColorDark">#FF7381F9</Color>

….

<ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButton"
                 TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
….

</UserControl.Resources>
Then modify the border radius in two places:
…
Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
            CornerRadius="<put a new radius here, for example 20>"
            BorderThickness="1">
…
And here
<Border Grid.Column="0"
            CornerRadius="<new value, for example 20>,0,0,<new value, for example 20>"
            Margin="1" >
```

This should do it. Since you did not specify the key name for the template the combobox should pick a new template up automatically.